# 'ENOENT': spawn cmd ENOENT error while authorizing sandbox org in VSCode

Tags: salesforcedx-cli, vs-code

Hi I have installed VS Code and salesfoce CLI, extensions also. I have created my first project. When i am tryin to authorize org in it i am getting below error:

```
Starting SFDX: Authorize an Org

14:22:31.109 sfdx force:auth:web:login --setalias vscodeOrg --instanceurl https://test.salesforce.com --setdefaultusername
 !    'ENOENT': spawn cmd ENOENT
14:22:44.830 sfdx force:auth:web:login --setalias vscodeOrg --instanceurl https://test.salesforce.com --setdefaultusername ended with exit code 1
```

Please help...!! Thanks

Comment: I am facing the same error. Any solutions for this?